# The definition of the $false$ truth value

Tags: logic, category-theory, self-learning, topos-theory

In "Topoi: The Categorial Analysis of Logic" by R. Goldblatt the $false: 1 \to \Omega$ truth value is defined as the characteristic arrow of the arrow $0_1: 0 \to 1$.  This definition requires that the arrow $0_1$ is mono.  Why is this true?

**UPD:**

For the proof see theorem 6.3 in "Elementary categories, elementary Toposes" by C. McLarty.  So thank you Zhen for referring to the notion of strict initial object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a topos (or more generally, any cartesian closed category with an initial object), $0$ is a strict initial object. That is, every morphism $X \to 0$ is an isomorphism. In particular, any parallel pair $X \rightrightarrows 0$ is degenerate. It follows that every morphism $0 \to Y$ is a monomorphism.

---

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a cartesian closed category, let $0$ be an initial object in $\mathcal{C}$, and let $f : X \to 0$ be a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$. Then we have $\langle \mathrm{id}_X, f \rangle : X \to X \times 0$ and a projection $p : X \times 0 \to X$. Of course, $p \circ \langle \mathrm{id}_X, f \rangle = \mathrm{id}_X$. But $X \times 0 \cong 0$ (because $\mathcal{C}$ is cartesian closed), so $X \cong 0$ as well. Hence $f : X \to 0$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you.  Why every morphism to 0 in a topos is an isomorphism? I tried to prove something like that, but failed.

Comment: I have added a paragraph.

Comment: By the way, the strictness of the initial object can be used to show that the category $\mathrm{Set}$ is not equivalent to its opposite category $\mathrm{Set}^\mathrm{op}$. Namely, in $\mathrm{Set}$ it is the case that any map into the initial object (the empty set) is an isomorphism. If $\mathrm{Set}$ were equivalent to $\mathrm{Set}^\mathrm{op}$, then it would also be true that any map from the terminal object (the singleton set $\{ \heartsuit \}$) is an isomorphism. But this is patently false, as any map $\{ \heartsuit \} \to \mathbb{R}$ illustrates.

Comment: I propose we call your singleton "the lonely heart", @IngoBlechschmidt.

Comment: @Omar: Love your suggestion! Just smuggled it into an [exercise sheet for a course on model categories](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iblech/modellkategorien/master/uebung01.pdf) (in German).